# Canvas, как панель для набора элементов, и Behaviors

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Мне нужно в качестве панели для элементов указать Canvas и подключить возможность перемещать элементы в ней.

Есть вот такая разметка.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MapObjects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:DragBehavior/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Из разметки видно, что для того, чтобы биндиться к аттачед свойствам `Canvas.Top/Left` понадобилось делать биндинг через стиль `ContentPresenter`, потому что каждый элемент оборачивается в `ContentPresenter`. А вот `Behaviors` я через стили указать не могу, потому что дизайнер ругается вот таким матом

> Свойство Behaviors не является DependencyProperty

Пробовал сделать так

```
<Setter Property="i:Interaction.Behaviors">
    <Setter.Value>
        <behaviors:DragBehavior/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

А в том виде, в котором это сейчас, оно не работает, потому что `AssociatedObject` в коде `DragBehavior` у меня является `ContentControl`. Я, конечно, могу найти нужный мне элемент по визуальному дереву, но что то мне подсказывает, что есть более изящный способ, который не будет так жестко привязан к разметке

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779168/5938996

Вот что получилось

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MapObjects}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <local:MyBehaviors x:Key="myBehaviors" x:Shared="False">
            <behaviors:DragBehavior/>
        </local:MyBehaviors>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="local:SupplementaryInteraction.Behaviors" Value="{StaticResource myBehaviors}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

И код

```
public class MyBehaviors : List<Behavior>
{

}

public static class SupplementaryInteraction
{
    public static MyBehaviors GetBehaviors(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (MyBehaviors)obj.GetValue(BehaviorsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBehaviors(DependencyObject obj, MyBehaviors value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BehaviorsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BehaviorsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Behaviors", typeof(MyBehaviors), typeof(SupplementaryInteraction), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyBehaviorsChanged));

    private static void OnPropertyBehaviorsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(d);
        foreach (var behavior in e.NewValue as MyBehaviors) behaviors.Add(behavior);
    }
}
```

Если кратко, `Behaviors` не является `DependencyProperty`. Исправляем это искусственно.